# Why and when did the practice of successive punctuation marks such as periods (...) originate in English sentence structure?

Tags: etymology, punctuation

Ex. "* The MS. is here deficient; but ....b for 'byrig' is discernible." ---Ingram. Source: Bede's Ecclesiastical History and the Anglo-Saxon Chronicle; Edited by J.A. Giles D.C.L.; London: George Bell & Sons, 1890, p.506

Comment: It has never originated in English sentence structure. English sentence structure refers to the **spoken** language. The practice arose in writing, not in the language it sposta represent.

Comment: @JohnLawler- Ok, a play on words then. How would you ask the question?

Comment: When did people start using ".." or "..." in English orthography? What did they use them for? Are ".." and "..." used differently?

Answer (score 1):

The name for this puncuation is "ellipsis" (plural "ellipses"), and it is not peculiar to English text. According to a comment [here](http://everything2.com/title/ellipsis)

> The ellipsis is first noted in Old Norse starting in about 200 BC,
>   which is the first known written language to utilize the ellipsis.
>   Often in Old Norse, writers would omit infinitive phrases and
>   non-action verbs, which is the first known existence of such verbal
>   omissions in written language. Old Norse was particularly well
>   structured for this because the language was contextually very strong;
>   writers and speakers were able to easily make it apparent what the
>   subjects and objects were, meaning the verb became less important in
>   many cases.
>
> Old Norse, through its evolution, came to impact the Romantic
>   languages greatly as a whole, so the use of the ellipsis is common
>   throughout the European languages, including German, Italian, French,
>   Spanish, and especially English.

Comment: And if that does not look like the most convincing source, searching on ellipsis and "Old Norse" brings up other corroborating sources.